# Angular compile from templateURL

Tags: angularjs

I have a function compiling a template successfully with an inline template; however when pulled from a templateURL it is not parsing the javascript values on compile.

Here is my controller logic:

```
$scope.$on('detail activated', function(event, args){

    $templateRequest("templates/ingredients-template.html").then(function(html){
          compileIngredients(html);   
     });
    function compileIngredients(html){
        for (var i = 0; i < args.ingredients; i++) {        
          var el = $compile(html)($scope); 
          $('ingredient').append(el);
        }
    }
```

Here is my template:

```
<div class="panel panel-default ingredients container-fluid" style="position: relative;">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="vm.removeIngredient($event, vm)" style=\"float: right; position: absolute; right: 20px; top: 13px;\">ingredient  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
   <h4 class="panel-heading">Ingredient "+(i+1)+"</h4>
      <div class="panel-body">
      <formly-form model="vm.model.ingredients["i"]" fields="vm.fields.ingredients["i"]"> </formly-form>
</div>
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'i"]"' is not a valid attribute name.
```

Comment: Replace `model="vm.model.ingredients["i"]"` with `model="vm.model.ingredients['i']"` (notice the single/double quotes)

Comment: thanks! For some reason, the page renders but with "vm.model.ingredients['i'].quantity" instead of "vm.model.ingredients[0].quantity"

Comment: Ah, ok, then `i` is a numeric index. You have to use `model="vm.model.ingredients[i]"`.